# passing an array to a rails button_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

the following

```
@ids.class
```

is being properly returned as `Array`
But when it is being used as values

```
<%= button_tag 'Top', value: @ids, type: :submit, name: :top %>
```

the params submitted are:

```
"top"=>"17515 30784 31614 32342 32362 31815 31813 32386 33004 32483 31750 32478 16331 11728"
```

which is a string.

```
>  params[:top].class
String
```

Transforming via Array(params[:top]) only results in a single element

```
["17515 30784 31614 32342 32362 31815 31813 32386 33004 32483 31750 32478 16331 11728"]
```

Transforming via substitution of space with a comma, to then generate a proper array

```
params[:top].sub(" ", ",")
```

only handles the first space

```
"17515,30784 31614 32342 32362 31815 31813 32386 33004 32483 31750 32478 16331 11728"
```

Modifying the tag to `value: @ids.to_s` returns the same situation.

How can this be properly processed by the subsequent action as an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can this be properly processed by the subsequent action as an array?

Unless you want to do some wonky parameter processing like `params[:top].split(' ')` you need to use multiple parameters in a form or query string to pass an array.

To pass array parameters in Rack (the CGI that Rails sits on top of) you need to pass multiple formdata pairs where the key ends with `[]`.

```
foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3
# resulting params hash
=> { "foo" => ["1", "2", "3"] }
```

This is actually processed the same way regardless if its passed in the query string or request body.

For query strings `#to_query` handles this automatically:

```
irb(main):004:0> CGI.unescape( { foo: [1,2,3]}.to_query )
=> "foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3"
```

For forms you can just create hidden inputs:

```
<% values.each do |v| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'top[]', v %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Max's answer is correct but will use `n` hidden form fields to generate the `foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3` response.
If you still want to use it with the `button_tag` input field you can do something like the following

```
# In your form file
<%= button_tag 'Top', value: @ids, type: :submit, name: :top %>
```

And then use it like that in your controller

```
# Use #split on the string params
params[:top].split
```

Example

```
"10 20 30".split => ["10", "20", "30"]
```

You can always pass a delimiter to split by on the `#split` method

[#split documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split)

Comment: Both of these answers are useful.  Max's answer is more enlightening.  The end case solution depends on the context.  WIth hundreds of ids, inspecting the generated HTML is more tedious than in the context provided by this solution.

Comment: With houndreds of ids you should reconsider whatever you're doing...